# Bootstrap class defined in HTML not appearing in DOM?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Ransack `search_form_for` with a `select` and two `input` fields.

I'm using Bootstrap classes for all of them, but whatever I define as a class for the `select` doesn't show up in the DOM.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3 my-2" >
    <%= search_form_for @search, { url: admin_invoices_batch_edit_index_path, method: :get } do |f| %>
      <%= f.select :status_eq, ["scheduled", "unpaid"], class: "form-control", include_blank: "Estado del recibo" %>
      <%= f.search_field :due_date_gteq, as: :string, placeholder: "Fecha de inicio para filtro",

                    data:{
                      controller: "flatpickr",
                      attributes:{ enableTime: false, enableSeconds: false }
                    }, class: "my-1 form-control col-auto"
                   %>

      <%= f.search_field :due_date_lteq, as: :string, placeholder: "Fecha de fin para filtro",
                    data:{
                      controller: "flatpickr",
                      attributes:{ enableTime: false, enableSeconds: false }
                    }, class: "my-1 form-control col-auto"
                   %>
      <%= f.submit "Filtrar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Borrar filtros", admin_invoices_batch_edit_index_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' if any_filter %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

`select` in DOM ("form-control" class is missing):

```
<select name="q[status_eq]" id="q_status_eq"><option value="">Estado del recibo</option>
<option value="scheduled">scheduled</option>
<option selected="selected" value="unpaid">unpaid</option></select>
```

If I inspect the `select` field in the DOM I would expect it to have `class = "form-control"` but it doesn't show up (it doesn't matter what I define as class for it in the HTML it won't show up).

Adding the class through the DOM works just fine (of course I loose that when I refresh the page).

But why is the class not added to the DOM in the first place?

Comment: [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-a-ruby-on-rails-application) may helps to you.

Comment: I think I'm missing something; did you (or can you) show the code where this `select_tag` class is created and then used? It's not anywhere in the code block you labeled "HTML", so it can't show up when that block is rendered to the DOM.

Comment: @oooyaya what do you mean? The select_tag definition and class is the third line in that block.

Comment: That creates a `select` tag. That tag does not have any `select_tag` class on it. You either want to rename your `.select_tag {...}` css rule to just `select {...}` (notice no `_tag` suffix and no `.` prefix) or add `class="select_tag"` to line 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think class option should go [as the forth argument](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L163)

```
<%= f.select :status_eq, ["scheduled", "unpaid"], { include_blank: "Estado del recibo" }, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: I moved it as the last argument and it didn't work. Also putting class:.. between {} broke the view.

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 edited my answer , did it change anything?

Comment: no, sorry. The class still doesn't show up in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code to be sure this is what's happening, but it looks like somewhere you probably have

```
.select_tag { ... }
```

The "dot" before `select_tag` means "make this a CSS class", so it can be used later on in the `<something class="...">` markup.

If that's close to what you have, then you want to change your HTML block to something like this to reference this CSS class.

```
<div class="col-md-3 my-2" >
    <%= search_form_for @search, { url: admin_invoices_batch_edit_index_path, method: :get } do |f| %>



      // the change is on this line: class: "form-control select_tag"
      <%= f.select :status_eq, ["scheduled", "unpaid"], class: "form-control select_tag", include_blank: "Estado del recibo" %>




      <%= f.search_field :due_date_gteq, as: :string, placeholder: "Fecha de inicio para filtro",

                    data:{
                      controller: "flatpickr",
                      attributes:{ enableTime: false, enableSeconds: false }
                    }, class: "my-1 form-control col-auto"
                   %>

      <%= f.search_field :due_date_lteq, as: :string, placeholder: "Fecha de fin para filtro",
                    data:{
                      controller: "flatpickr",
                      attributes:{ enableTime: false, enableSeconds: false }
                    }, class: "my-1 form-control col-auto"
                   %>
      <%= f.submit "Filtrar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Borrar filtros", admin_invoices_batch_edit_index_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' if any_filter %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Alternately, you could rename the CSS rule to something like this, but this will affect all `<select>` tags so it's not recommended.  Doing it this way, your HTML doesn't need to change since you're affecting the element (`<select>`) and not a class within it (`<select class="select_tag">`)

```
select { ... }
```

Comment: We don't have .select_tag defined. The main problem is that whatever I define as class for the select field doesn't show up in the DOM (I inspect the field and it doesn't have any class where I would expect it to have class="form-control" ).

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 ooooooh. OK, I understand the problem now.  You expect `class="form-control"` to be in the DOM since you have `class: "form-control"` in your Ransack template, but that isn't happening. I'll poke some more and see what I can come up with now that I understand.  Disregard this answer.  I was thinking you wanted some other class to be added.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain correctly. I added that to the OP. Thanks for your help! @oooyaya